# Multitasking Apps may only use background services for their intended purposes:

Tags: ios

Reasons

2.16: Multitasking Apps may only use background services for their intended purposes: VoIP, audio playback, location, task completion, local notifications, etc.
----- 2.16 -----

We found that your app uses a background mode but does not include functionality that requires that mode to run persistently. This behavior is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

We noticed your app declares support for audio in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist, but no audible content is played when the application is in the background. While your intention may have been to provide this functionality, at the time of review, we were not able to play background audio for your app.

As indicated in the iOS Application Programming Guide:

"This key is intended for use by applications that provide audible content to the user while in the background, such as music-player or streaming-audio applications."

Therefore, it would be appropriate to provide audible content to the user while the app is in the background or remove the "audio" setting from the UIBackgroundModes key.

If you have difficulty reproducing a reported issue, please try testing the workflow described in Technical Q&A QA1764: How to reproduce bugs reported against App Store submissions.

If you have code-level questions after utilizing the above resource, you may wish to consult with Apple Developer Technical Support. When the DTS engineer follows up with you, please be ready to provide:

- complete details of your rejection issue(s)
- screenshots
- steps to reproduce the issue(s)
- symbolicated crash logs - if your issue results in a crash log

here is my code

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
      UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

       bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

        }];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            musTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10
                                                        target:self
                                                      selector:@selector(playmus)
                                                      userInfo:nil
                                                       repeats:YES];

            //run function methodRunAfterBackground
            t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:delay
                                                 target:self
                                               selector:@selector(sendLocalNotification)
                                               userInfo:nil
                                                repeats:YES];
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:t forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:musTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
        });


    }
}
-(void)playmus
{
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier newTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mute" ofType:@"mp3"]];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];

    [audioPlayer play];



    newTaskId = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:NULL];

    if (newTaskId != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid && bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask: bgTask];

    bgTask = newTaskId;

}
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: I can not understund how fixe this

Comment: is your app an application for playing music?

Comment: no but in my code i play music on backgraunde

Comment: my app played music on backgraunde mode

Comment: Does it successfully play music?  From Apple's comments it seems that it doesn't.  From the looks of your filename you are playing a 'silent' mp3 file - is this correct? If so then that is why you are being rejected.  Silence is not audio unless you are this guy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4′33″